# Action of module automorphism group

Tags: abstract-algebra

It can be proven that for any vector space $V$ the action of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ on $V \setminus \{0\}$ is transitive, and its stabilizer is $U^* \rtimes GL(U)$, where $U$ is a complement to the subspace spanned by some non-zero vector from $V$. The proof that I found relies heavily on the fact that any non-zero vector can be extended to a basis, so naturally it's a useless tactic for modules.

Can this proposition be generalized to modules or at least some class of modules larger than vector spaces? What proof strategy would you suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one counterexample: for $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, we have that $\text{GL}(\mathbb{Z})=\{\pm1\}$, which does not act transitively on $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.

If we want even the claim that $\text{GL}(M)$ acts transitively on $M\setminus\{0\}$ for any $R$-module $M$ to be true, then it must be true for $R$ treated as an $R$-module, so we need $\text{GL}(R)=R^\times$ to act transitively on $R\setminus\{0\}$, i.e. for any $x,y\in R\setminus\{0\}$ there is a unit $u$ such that $y=ux$. In particular, for every $x\in R\setminus\{0\}$, we have that $x=u\cdot1=u$ for some unit $u$, i.e. every non-zero element is a unit, i.e. $R$ is a field. So this won't be true for anything other than vector spaces.